# How can I see what is the number of embedded objects used by a site in html from a wireshark trace?

Tags: wireshark, embedded

I have recorded a wireshark trace and visited some websites. I exported the trace as a CSV file. How can I see the number of embedded objects in each of the sites I visited? Thanks.

Comment: In wire shark [export objects http](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html#ChIOExportObjectsDialog) maybe? In general a protocol specific tool such as  the developer tools for your web browser or something like Fiddler that tracks requests is a much more user friendly and efficient way to analyze your own web traffic than a packet filter.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Requests by HTTP Host
Go to [Statistics](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseStatisticsMenuSection.html) - HTTP
Select Requests
Hit Create Stat.

You can apply a [display filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters), for instance:
http.host == "www.lovemytool.com"